# Where is the request code constant (64206) for login defined in Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK (4.*) on Android.
Just implemented programmatically login (without using "LoginButton") using `LoginManager`'s `logInWithReadPermissions()`. In order for callback to work I need to call `FacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` which I do in my activity's `onActivityResult` method.

However, my `onActivityResult` handles results form several returning activities and it checks the `requestCode` to see which activity returned. I see that facebook login returns with 64206 but I am unable to find where that constant is defined. I don't want to hardcode 64206 and I was wondering: does someone knows where is this result code defined in the Facebook SDK (and is it public)?

Comment: the request code `64206` is simply `0xface`. Check the answer bellow.

Comment: Similarly, the request code `64207` is `CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Share.toRequestCode()`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So after all I decided to dig in with the debugger and found it in the `Facebook SDK`. Request codes are defined in `CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset`.

You can get the login request code with this:
`CallbackManagerImpl.RequestCodeOffset.Login.toRequestCode()`.

There you will find also codes for `Share`, `Message`, `Like`, `GameRequest`, `AppGroupCreate`, `AppGroupJoin`, `AppInvite`.

Answer (score 6):

Better way is to call
FacebookSdk.getCallbackRequestCodeOffset()

Comment: After checking FacebookSdk, I found there is a method  boolean isFacebookRequestCode(int requestCode).

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't really have to care about the actual value of Facebook's internally used request code, as the result of `CallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` will tell you whether it was handled or not. That is, first offer the result to the `CallbackManager`. If it indicates it was handled, you're all done. If it wasn't handled, it is one of your other request code's results, so just continue with the logic you already have in place.

From the [docs on `CallbackManager`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/1cb3863835ccf10d4ee6e1919a02f7d4e76748b9/facebook/src/com/facebook/CallbackManager.java):

```
/**
 * The method that should be called from the Activity's or Fragment's onActivityResult method.
 * @param requestCode The request code that's received by the Activity or Fragment.
 * @param resultCode  The result code that's received by the Activity or Fragment.
 * @param data        The result data that's received by the Activity or Fragment.
 * @return true If the result could be handled.
 */
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
```

Note the `@return` remark.

So basically, your code should be structured somewhat like this:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    boolean handled = callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (handled) { /* all done */ }
    else { /* result wasn't handled by the callback manager, so check for other potential request codes */ }
}
```

If you really want, you can dive into the Facebook SDK source to trace the origin of the request code. In particular, refer to [`CallbackManagerImpl`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/1cb3863835ccf10d4ee6e1919a02f7d4e76748b9/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/CallbackManagerImpl.java), where the static callbacks are set up with a predefined request code offset.

Comment: There are two issues with this approach: 1. The bigger issue: I don't want to call external code with the result `Intent data` which (may) contains sensitive information. 2. The smaller issue: it is not efficient (and it is messy). What if i have to call trough several external onActivityResult handlers each time, e.g. if I use several external libs...

Comment: @Ogre_BGR: 1. Then just invert the if-else, so you don't get to the else if there was a 'sensitive data case' (if that's really what you're worried about, you shouldn't be using *any* libraries though, so a bit of a moot point). 2. Subjective at best. You say messy, someone else may argue the opposite as the result is then handled within the context its request was fired from. Also depends on how you define efficiency: having a dedicated handler is an easy approach to avoid code duplication. Anyways, in the end it's up to you. All I did is provide a sensible solution to your problem. :)

Comment: Yes, it is subjective but I tend to gravitate toward explicit request code comparison. There is one thing that bothers me with the solution I provided in the answer to my own question is that `RequestCodeOffset` is nested in `CallbackManagerImpl` and if facebook decides to provide new `CallbackManager` implementation they may deprecate `CallbackManagerImpl` and my code will have to be changed (but in the case of FB we suffered trough this several times already so no big deal :-)).

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong if you need to handle multiple activity results in the same onActivityResult() method, e.g., if you want to also handle Google sign-in.

Comment: @user3562927: And why's that? Who's preventing you from adding more request code checks in the `else`, or even before the whole if-else condition?

Comment: @MH. -- I apologize.  I misread and/or misunderstood your reply the first time.  It looks 100% correct now that I've re-read it.

Answer (score 2):

The request code is merely a pun to `0xface` in hexadecimal (or 64206 in decimal), as it can be seen at [FacebookSdk.DEFAULT_CALLBACK_REQUEST_CODE_OFFSET](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be dependent on request code defined by Facebook. You can set own. Do not initialize Facebook SDK at app star (what you should not do due to performance reason) so do not add lines below to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb..." />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="fb..." />
```

And you init it whenever je want/need (in our case after uses click at Facebook Login feature)

```
if (!FacebookSdk.isInitialized()) {
    FacebookSdk.setApplicationId("...");
    FacebookSdk.setClientToken("...");
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext(), yourOwnRequestCode);
}
```

Do not bother warn that method FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() is marked as deprecated. Facebook marked is as deprecated but they says `This method can bee called manually if needed.` (so I think it should never be marked as deprecated, not everyone wishes auto init at app start )
( https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commit/e610fe89f44dad8c4402fb34d0eb68abe4522af2#diff-1b1024d6bc6def0e7c192dab15687476 )

Consider adding following into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoInitEnabled" android:value="false" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled" android:value="false" />
```